# Why does my code to print prime numbers terminate early?

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, logic, primes

I tried to make program in C to print all prime numbers from 2 to a given no.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int up, t = 1, i, j;
    puts("This program will show you a list of all prime numbers from 2 to the number you enter below: ");
    scanf("%d", &up);
    for(i == 2; i <= up; i++) {
        for(j == 1; j <= sqrt(i); j++) {
            if(i % j != 0) {
                t = 0;
            }
            if(t == 1) {
                printf("%d", i);
            }
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Returns the following result:

```
$ gcc prime.c -lm
$ ./a.out

This program will show you a list of all prime numbers from 2 to the number you enter below: 
10
```

I mean, after I enter 10, the program terminates.
Ideas?
Thank You.

Comment: `i == 2` Where did you learn this?

Comment: This `if(t == 1) {..}` should go after the inner loop.

Comment: ...and `t` should be initialised before the `j` loop begins. You can also `break` from the inner loop as soon as you find a divisor.

Comment: ALWAYS request warnings from your compiler and heed them. This would have found two of your problems. (I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`.)

Comment: @ikegami I have assigned t = 1 in the beginning. Thanks a ton for the warnings idea.

Comment: Woops! Sorry, Incorrect comment deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible fixed version of your program.

Note that you should start division at 2 and not at 1.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main() {
        int up, i, j;
        int prime;

        puts("This program will show you a list of all prime numbers from 2 to the number you enter below: ");
        scanf("%d", &up);
        for(i = 2; i <= up; i++) {
            prime = 1;
            for(j = 2; j <= sqrt(i); j++) {
                if(i % j == 0) {
                  prime = 0;
                }
             }
            if (prime == 1)
              printf("%d ", i);
        } 
        printf("\n");
        return(0);
    }
```

Example:

```
$ ./prime
This program will show you a list of all prime numbers from 2 to the number you enter below: 
10
2 3 5 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isprime(int num){
    int loop; /* loop variable */
    for(loop=2;loop<num;++loop){
        if(num % loop==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    puts("This program will show you a list of all prime numbers from 2 to the number you enter below: ");
    int up;
    scanf("%d", &up);
    if (isprime(up)){
        printf("It is a prime number\n");
    } else{
        printf("It is not a prime number\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Looks like you are a student. You are using **==** which is a comparison operator. You have to use **=** in loop. Learn more .